# Is there a site for general computer questions / very basic questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been searching for answers to a very simple computer question. I'm just a home computer user, I don't work with computers and am no expert in any way. When I search, it returns a lot of answers, mostly from Stack Overflow and other programming sites. Is there a site here for "general computing" or "computer beginners"?

My question is about the difference in using the Tab key and the space key to create spacing between words. Seems they work differently; TAB separates words with "available space" (for lack of a proper term; Im not computer literate) and space key separates words with "invisible but space-filling" blocks?

Comment: Most likely [superuser](https://superuser.com) is where you want to ask your question. Be sure to read their [help](https://superuser.com/help) center first to see if your question is a fit for the site. Could you edit this current question of yours and give an example of what type of question you plan to ask.

Answer (score 3):

The Stack Exchange network never rejects any "too basic" questions, provided they show enough research effort prior to asking.

For any questions about "general computer", I would recommend [Super User](https://superuser.com). Make sure you've read [What's on topic?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on that site before asking.

Answer (score 3):

To an extent - if it involves a PC and you've taken at least a minimal effort to research Super User's the right site. Its worth remembering that there's a few quirks to SU (and this is where my answer is distinct from iDebug's) - If its about *how* to use a piece of software, finding out how to get software to do a thing you need or talking about getting your system to perform a task (since [we don't do straight software recommendations](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)) its probably fine.

If you need a software recommendation - [there's a site for that](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). There's also a few other sites ([android](https://android.stackexchange.com) for android, [ask different for apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com) and a few linux sites that overlap in scope with Super User and Server Fault that are worth being aware of as well.

Typical, end user issues is definitely within the scope of Super User.